# Project generation problem using Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo

I just downloaded SpringSource Tool Suite, and tried to generate a demo application using roo, but i'm getting error below

Code:

```
Created /home/dev/springsource/workspace/demo/pom.xml
Undo create /home/dev/springsource/workspace/demo/pom.xml
Invalid dependency scope: PROVİDED
[Timer-0] NullPointerException at org.springframework.roo.classpath.itd.AbstractItdMetadataProvider.notify(AbstractItdMetadataProvider.java:84)
```

What is the problem? is this Maven issue?

Using: Ubuntu 8.10, SpringSource Tool Suite Version: 2.3.3.M1, Roo 1.1.0.M1, Apache Maven

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to JVM arguments in roo.sh:
-Duser.language=en

HTH

Answer (score 1):

an addition; 
if you are using STS, you also have to add "-Duser.language=en" to sts.ini